# How to run Firefox full screen in minimalist X environment

Tags: firefox, x11, centos5, kiosk

I wish to set up what is usually called a Kiosk, running Firefox locked down to our own specific home page (and links from there). The base operating system is CentOs 5 (i.e. just like RedHat Enterprise 5).

Ideally I want Firefox to start full screen (and I have installed the full-fullscreen addon to help with this), and to be locked as such (i.e. F11 does not work).

I need to be able to install this system using one or more rpm files.

I have tested my fullscreen Firefox setup rpm under Gnome, and it works fine - my Gnome desktop is 1024x768, and the selected home page comes up exactly filling the screen - looks great.

However, I do not want to bother with a desktop environment (like Gnome or KDE), just run Firefox as the sole X client program, with a fixed screen size of 1024x768.

I have built rpms to install X, configure it to run at 1024x768, and fire up X automatically from an autologin using shell scripts.

My main autologon script contains this:

```
startx ~/client/xClient.sh  -- :1 &
```

xClient.sh contains this:

```
while [ true ]
do
    firefox
done
```

My problem is that Firefox does not come up full screen under this setup. The firefox window is smaller than the screen, and the top left corner is off the screen - this means the web page gets scrollbars, the top and left of the page does not show, and there is a black area along the bottom and right.

Does anyone know the reason for this behaviour?

What solutions can you suggest?

I suppose, if necessary, I could install Gnome on the machine, and then try to lock it down - but it seems silly to add something as complex as Gnome just to get the window to appear the right size, and in the right place! Plus there is the extra task of trying to lock Gnome down so the users can't do anything else with the machine.

If you think this question should not be on Stack Overflow, please tell me where it should go. (I think writing rpm and shell scripts are programming, but maybe they don't count? If not, sorry!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have a similar setup to yours and after a little testing decided to use a tiling window manager instead of just running chrome or firefox in X. A tiling window manager will give you fullscreen regardless of application and many will not have the windows borders/decorations, also great for kiosks.

Xmonad works really well for touch screens; matchbox works well too depending on your use case. Awesome and ratpoison are other good alternatives. You will probably have better luck picking a very minimalist window manager than running directly on X.

http://www.alandmoore.com/blog/2011/11/05/creating-a-kiosk-with-linux-and-x11-2011-edition/

Xmonad has tons of hotkeys which would have to be disabled, so while perfect for touchscreens, may not be suitable for kiosks with keyboards. It does have great configuration documentation and a vibrant community -- but is not a drop-kick solution with keyboard equipped kiosks.

Answer (score 5):

You have 2 options. 
You install a kiosk plug-in, that allows you to start firefox automatically in full screen mode (amongst other things). One example would be [R-kiosk](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/r-kiosk/)

Or you skip firefox and create a xul application that does what you want. You can find a sample application [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Getting_started_with_XULRunner). And you can find full screen code (not tested) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381647/changing-the-content-of-browser-in-xulrunner).

Answer (score 4):

Maybe, it is worth looking at `xdotool` (it is not installed automatically, but present in Ubuntu repositories).

I hope something like

```
xdotool search --name ".*Mozilla Firefox" windowsize 1024 768
```

in your X startup script can help. Also you can adjust the window position and other window properties as needed.

Comment: Thanks for the thought. But, unless it can full-screen Firefox (i.e. remove the window furniture, title bar, etc., and remove any Gnome menus), it's not a lot of help.

Comment: You can send F11 key with `xdotool` to the window to make it fullscreen, then map F11 to something else or nothing with `xxkb` or `xmodmap`. Also, disabling the `alt` key would help to prevent changing to another virtual terminal (Ctrl-Alt-F1 etc) without hurting user experience a lot.

Comment: I don't know why, but this just crashes the X server for me on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. If I run it inside a desktop environment purely nothing happens.

Comment: The crash is worth reporting anyways, but kiosk mode is usually done with a fullscreen-aware app (it's way more than just window size, especially for an OS equivalent that these browsers became) _and_ a minimalistic/"invisible" window manager like ratpoison to care for dialog windows of that app, if any; things like keyboars layout setup (and/or on-screen keyboard) are rather done in one-shot manner during X session startup.

Comment: Dmitry, there are DontVTSwitch and DontZap xorg.conf options :-)  Major X-capable browsers tend to implement fullscreen/kiosk commandline options for quite some time, see livecd-webkiosk.spec link in my (edited) answer.  Glad to see you alive too!

Answer (score 0):

Just my two copecks, there's a [self-contained RPM spec](http://git.altlinux.org/people/mike/packages/?p=livecd-webkiosk.git;a=blob;f=livecd-webkiosk.spec;hb=HEAD) building a set of packages aimed to provide webkiosk environment with various browsers out there; [2024] I used to build and publish "webkiosk" ISOs [/2024] and one can possibly adapt them as the technology to tweak/build ALT Linux based images is [published](http://git.altlinux.org/people/mike/packages/?p=mkimage-profiles.git) too [2024](feel free to ping and cooperate albeit I've also moved away from x86 since)[/2024].

Comment: The "these ISOs" link just leads to a page with an error log starting with "NoSuchKey".

Comment: Thank you; I've edited the post removing the 404 link as that led to our community-run hosting in Kiev which got discontinued in 2014/2015 (greetings from Moscow, I'm alive!).  If you might still need those, drop me a line at mike@altlinux.org and let's see what can be done now (I haven't built x86 images for quite some time and this flavour didn't make it into altlinux.org/starterkits crop for the younger hands to cater to).